# Why is Orpah listed first?

Tags: marriage, book-of-ruth

In Rus 1:4 it says that Naomi's two sons married to Moabite women, Orpah and Rus. We know that Rus married Machlon (4:10) the older brother and Orpah, Rus's sister (Rus Rabba 2:9) married Kilyon. Why then does it list Orpah before Rus?

Furthermore, I realize that it is possible that Kilyon and Orpah married earlier than Machlon and Rus. However, I have found no source which says so, and it would seem that standard practice was to marry off the older sibling before the younger (bereshis 29:26).

Comment: I don't think that Bereshis can really be used to determine the standard practice in the time of Ruth. There's a big time gap there.

Comment: @Daniel I partially agree. At the very least it is a precedent, if something changed we should have a source which says so, no?

Comment: @nikmasi Why would you expect a source to tell us that something changed? The Torah tells us important things.

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm not expecting the torah to tell us something changed, i'm expected chazal or one of the commentators to do so, which, as far as I can see they do not. The fact that the torah tell us important things is the basis of my question. Apparently it is important to know that Orpah comes before Rus.

Comment: You expect Chazal to know about bronze age moabite dating customs? Funny, because most frum people today would call studying that Bitul Torah.

Comment: @DoubleAA no, but I do expect them to explain why the younger sister is mentioned before the older one.

Comment: They'll only do that if the younger sister is actually mentioned first, which we and they (apparently) don't know about because we and they don't know those moabite customs. How do you know anyway that Machlon is older than Kilyon?

Comment: @DoubleAA Me'am Loez to Rus 4:9

Comment: @DoubleAA also stated in Taama D’Kra [Rabbi Chaim Kanievsky shlit"a]

Comment: Interesting. How do they know?

Comment: @DoubleAA Ruach HaKodesh ;-)

Comment: @nikmasi Then you should include in your question that it is based on Ruach HaKodesh of R Chaim Kanievsky, as that fact is very important to your argument.

Comment: @DoubleAA ...or someone could bring an answer which disproves this point, say from the sefer meishiv nefer or the pirush of rabbenu vidal tzarfati. Perhaps Orpah was simply the older one?

Comment: So long as you don't include a source for it, I can answer without a source saying Kilyon is older because Kilyon is mentioned first in chapter 4. At that point you can't edit to include a source because it would invalidate my answer. Is that what you want?

Comment: @DoubleAA sounds good

Answer (score 4):

http://www.haravpinto.com/article.php?id=620:

> בתחילה נשא כליון, על אף היותו הצעיר שבבנים, את ערפה. לאחר מכן נשא מחלון את רות, משום כך הזכיר הפסוק את ערפה לפני רות.‏

In translation:

> *Kilyon* married *Orpa* first even though he was younger; then *Machlon* married *Rus*. That's why Scripture mentions *Orpa* before *Rus*.

Answer (score 0):

The Malbim learns from the order of this listing two points regarding the character of Machlon and Kilyon:

1) They had a lack of decency (מעוט המוסר) that the younger went and got married before the older, and the older did not protest.

2) Had Machlon gotten married first, there would be a partial vindication of the brothers, because Machlon could be said to have married Rus recognizing her piety as is born out through the rest of the story, and Kilyon for thinking that maybe he would find a woman as pious as his brother did.  But now that Kilyon got married first, and Orpah was not as pious as Rus (As we see from her not following through to return with Naomi), Kilyon had no precedent on which to base himself, and Machlon should have learned from how his younger brother had stumbled.